# Binding to list causes memory leak

Tags: c#, wpf, memory, binding, memory-leaks

When I bind an ItemsSource of a ListBox to a List the binding engine holds on to the list elements after the control is gone. This causes all the list elements to stay in memory. The problem goes away when using an ObservalbleCollection. Why does this happen?

The xaml inside the window tag

```
<Grid>
    <StackPanel>
        <ContentControl Name="ContentControl">
            <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding List, Mode=TwoWay}" DisplayMemberPath="Name"/>
        </ContentControl>
        <Button Click="Button_Click">GC</Button>
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

Code behind:

```
public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        DataContext = new ViewModel();
    }

private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        this.DataContext = null;
        ContentControl.Content = null;
        GC.Collect();
        GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
    }
```

ViewModel

```
class ViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    //Implementation of INotifyPropertyChanged ...

    //Introducing ObservableCollection as type resolves the problem
    private IEnumerable<Person> _list = 
            new List<Person> { new Person { Name = "one" }, new Person { Name = "two" } };

    public IEnumerable<Person> List
    {
        get { return _list; }
        set
        {
            _list = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("List");
        }
    }

class Person
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Edit: To check the leaking of the person istances, I used ANTS and .Net memory profiler. Both show that after pushing the GC-button only the binding engine is holding reference to the person objects.

Comment: What do you mean by "control is gone"? Has it become invisible? Was it unloaded ?

Comment: How you know about memory leaks here? What tool have you used to profile this?

Comment: how to identify that memory is going leaks in case when you are using List.

Comment: you should change the List from IEnumerable<Person> to ObservableCollection<Person>

Answer (score 7):

Ahhh got you. Now I understand what you mean.

You set the Content to null and so you kill the compelte ListBox but still the ItemsSource binds to List and so ListBox memory is not completely released.

That is unfortunately a well known issue and also well documented on MSDN.

If you are not binding to a DependencyProperty or a object that implements INotifyPropertyChanged or ObservableCollection then the binding can leak memory, and you will have to unbind when you are done.

This is because if the object is not a DependencyProperty or does not implement INotifyPropertyChanged or not implementing INotifyCollectionChanged (Normal list is not implementing this) then it uses the ValueChanged event via the PropertyDescriptors AddValueChanged method. This causes the CLR to create a strong reference from the PropertyDescriptor to the object and in most cases the CLR will keep a reference to the PropertyDescriptor in a global table.

Because the binding must continue to listen for changes. This behavior keeps the reference alive between the PropertyDescriptor and the object as the target remains in use. This can cause a memory leak in the object and any object to which the object refers.

The question is...is Person implementing INotifyPropertyChanged?

Comment: Person is not implementing INotifyPropertyChanged. But I understood the well-known problem differently. I understood that the class that is providing the property should implement INotifyPropertyChanged, which it does. "it uses the ValueChanged event via the PropertyDescriptors AddValueChanged method" makes only sense when the class providing the property is meant, right?

Comment: No, not really, you are almost there. Think like this: Every property in a ViewModel has a type. That type might be another class which shall implement INotifyPropertyChanged. ViewModel itself should implement INotifyPropertyChanged too. When Binding inits it takes the type of the property and seeks for interfaces like INotifyPropertyChanged or INotifyCollectionChanged. List<> is at type has no interface while ObservableCollection does. If no interface found it will take a strong reference (Not in every case). Sometimes Binding takes a weak reference. To sum up its the type that owns property.

Comment: I am very grateful that you take time to respond to my question. I tested your original theory that is has something to do with "is Person implementing INotifyPropertyChanged". It has not. Whether the person objects are kept in memory is indepented of whether Person implements INotifyPropertyChanged. It does only depend on the type of the list. Type List means it stays, type ObservableCollection means it goes away.

Comment: My understanding of the problem of static references to the ValueChanged-event is this: ValueChanged is an event of a PropertyDescriptor which represents a property -- the property of the binding source object. The Binding source in this example is the ViewModel. But, it is of type INotifyPropertyChanged, therefore the issue does not apply here.

Comment: Read again what I wrote. Of course it is not changing anything when you even implement INotifyPropertyChanged in Person. You keep misunderstanding what I am saying. The Binding itself looks at the type of the property which is in your case List<..> and it asks that type if it has interfaces implement. It doesnt so the Binding creates a strong reference in your case. If the type of the property was a class that did implement INotifyPropertyChanged such as Person alone (not in a list and with implemented interface) it would work. List is a class without INotifyCollectionChanged interface.

Comment: I made the following test: I created a Person Person {...} property on ViewModel. This property contains a new Person{Name = "one"} instance. The Person class is not implementing INotifyPropertyChanged. I added a TextBlock to the view within the ContentControl:<TextBlock Text="{Binding Person.Name, Mode=TwoWay}"/>. After I press GC the Person instance is gone. It is gone when Person is implementing INotifyPropertyChanged, it is gone when Person is not implementing INotifyPropertyChanged. I think my tests disprove your otherwise very good theory.

Comment: I assume the cause of the behavior is connected to the default collection view. ObservableCollection seems to have a different default collection view then List. As you can read in the official WPF doku, internally, ItemSource bindings bind to a collection view. If no collectio view is specified explicitly, a default collection view is created internally to be used in the binding. Unfortunately, I have to give up the research on this issue. Thank you for your help and contribution.

Comment: No, it does not have to do with collection views. The collection view is always default except you write your own and you implement ICollectionView interface. Its the weak event pattern provided in WeakPropertyChangedEventManager that is being switched between ItemsSource and your collection of items. If you collection of items is of type ObservableCollection the WeakPropertyChangedEventManager will know where to subscribe to. If not the Binding will not use weak event pattern but instead it will use strong refs to source and its own property value changed mechanism.

Comment: About your new tests. Read again what I wrote. "If no interface found it will take a strong reference (Not in every case). Sometimes Binding takes a weak reference." I am not sure when binding does take weak reference to source and when it creates a strong one. The person reference in your test that you used as source in binding was seen as a weak reference inside Binding.

Comment: The solution is anyways to use ObservableCollection for everything in WPF. Even microsoft tells you to do so. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms668604.aspx

Comment: @devhedgehog, but I didn't get your statement "If you are not binding to a DependencyProperty...." ItemsSource is DependencyProperty, or you're talking about the object that is being bound to ItemsSource? If so, in case of having the View closed, then should have no problem? Am I right? – Abdulkarim Kanaan 17 mins ago

Comment: The issue is not related to data binding but to CollectionViews in general. If you were right then WPF data binding would be very restricted and bindings to e.g., XML or DataTable would not be "possible". The leak is not a leak. It's the result of the way the binding engine/WPF manages CollectionViews, which significantly extends the lifetime of CollectionViews and their collections in case the collection does not implement INotifyCollectionChanged.

Answer (score 4):

That's an old post, I see. But the explanations provided, especially by the accepted answer, are not very accurate and the implications are wrong.

### Abstract

Beforehand, this is not a real memory leak. The special binding engine's lifetime management for collections that do not implement `INotifyCollectionChanged` and their associated `CollectionView` takes proper care of the allocated memory.
WPF supports binding to many different types like `DataTable` and XML or in general to types that implement `IList`, `IEnumerable` or `IListSource`. If this was a serious bug, then all those bindings would be dangerous.
Microsoft would propagate warnings in their docs against e.g., binding to `DataTable` like they are doing in case of potential memory leaks in context with events or data binding.

It is indeed true that this special behavior can be avoided by

a) binding to a collection of type `INotifyCollectionChanged`
b) avoiding creating a `CollectionView` for a collection that does not implement `INotifyCollectionChanged`
c) clearing the source collection after use *if* the collection does not implement `INotifyCollectionChanged`), so that only the empty collection will reside in memory until the binding engine releases it.

because the observed behavior is actually induced by the actual `CollectionView` management of the binding engine and not the data binding itself. The binding engine can manage the lifetime of the source collection and the associated `ICollectionView` more efficiently when it is enabled to listen to the `INotifyCollectionCHanged.CollectionChanged` event.

The following code triggers the same behavior as would do a binding to a `List<T>`:

```
var list = new List<int> {1, 2, 3};
ICollectionView listView = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(list);
list = null;
listView = null;
for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
{
  GC.Collect(2, GCCollectionMode.Forced, true);
  GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
}
```

Result: the entire collection reference graph and the `CollectionView` are still in memory (see explanation below).
This should be proof that the behavior *is not* introduced by data binding, but by the binding engine's `CollectionView` management.

---

### Memory Leaks in Context of Data binding

The memory leak issue regarding data binding is not related to the type of the property, but to the notification system that the binding source implements.
The source must either
      a) participate in the dependency property system (by extending `DependencyObject` and by implementing properties as `DependencyProperty`) or
      b) implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`

Otherwise, the binding engine will create a **static** reference to the source. Static references are root references. Due to their nature to be reachable during the lifetime of the application, such root references, like static fields and every object (memory) they reference, will never be eligible for garbage collection and thus create the actual memory leak.

### Collections and `CollectionView` Management

Collections are a different story. The cause of the **alleged leak** is not the data binding itself. It's the binding engine that is also responsible for creating the `CollectionView` of the actual collections.
Whether the `CollectionView` is created in context of a binding or when calling `CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView`: it's the binding engine that creates and manages the views.

The relationship between collection and `CollectionView` is a unidirectional dependency, where the `CollectionView` knows the collection in order to synchronize itself, while the collection does not know the `CollectionView`.

Every existing `CollectionView` is managed by the `ViewManager`, which is part of the binding engine. To improve performance, the view manager caches views: it stores them in a `ViewTable` using `WeakReference` to allow them to be garbage collected.

### When a collection implements `INotifyCollectionChanged`

```html
           │══════ strong reference R1.1 via event handler ═══════▶⎹
Collection │                                                        │ CollectionView
           │◀═══  strong reference R1.2 for lifetime management ═══⎹       ̲ ̲          
                                                                            △                                                                                                                  
                                                                            │
                                                                            │                                 
                                   ViewTable │───── weak reference W1 ──────┘
```

The `CollectionView` itself is target of a strong reference *R1.1* from the underlying source collection if this collection implements `INotifyCollectionChanged`.
This strong reference *R1.1* is created by the `CollectionView` the moment it observes the `INotifyCollectionChanged.CollectionChanged` event (by attaching an event callback that the collection stores in order to invoke it when raising the event).

This way, the lifetime of the `CollectionView` is coupled to the lifetime of the collection: even if the application has no references to a `CollectionView`, because of these strong references the lifetime of the `CollectionView` is extended until the collection itself is eligible for garbage collection.
Since the `CollectionView` instances are stored in the `ViewTable` as `WeakReference` *W1*, this lifetime coupling prevents the `WeakReference` *W1* from getting garbage collected prematurely.
In other words, this strong coupling *R1.1* prevents the `CollectionView` from being garbage collected *before* the collection.

Additionally, the manager must also guarantee that as long as the `CollectionView` is referenced by the application, the underlying collection continues to exist, even if this collection is no longer referenced. This is achieved by keeping a strong reference *R1.2* from `CollectionView` to the source collection.
This reference always exists, no matter the collection type.

### When a collection does not implement `INotifyCollectionChanged`

```html
Collection │◀═══  strong reference R2.1 for lifetime management ════│ CollectionView
                                                                           ̲ ̲                                                                             
                                                                            ▲
                                                                            ║
                                                                            ║
                                 ViewTable │════ strong reference R2.2 ═════╝
```

Now, when the collection *does not* implement `INotifyCollectionChanged`, then the required strong reference from collection to `CollectionView` does not exist (because no event handlers are involved) and the `WeakReference` stored in the `ViewTable` to the `CollectionView` could be potentially garbage collected prematurely.
To fix this, the view manager must keep the `CollectionView` "artificially" alive.

It does this by storing a strong reference *R2.2* to the `CollectionView`. At this moment the view manager has stored a strong reference *R2.2* to the `CollectionView` (due to the lack of `INotifyCollectionChanged`) while this `CollectionView` has a strong reference *R2.1* to the underlying collection.
This results in the view manager keeping the `CollectionView` alive (*R2.2*) and therefore the `CollectionView` keeps the underlying collection alive (*R2.1*): this is the cause for the *perceived* memory leak.

But this is not a real leak, as the view manager controls the lifetime of the strong reference *R2.2* to the `CollectionView` by registering the strong reference *R2.2* with an expiration date. This date is renewed on each access to the `CollectionView`.

The view manager will now occasionally purge those references when their expiration date is expired. Finally, those references will get collected when
the `CollectionView` is not referenced by the application (ensured by the garbage collector) and the underlying collection is no longer referenced (ensured by the garbage collector).

This behavior is introduced to allow the strong reference *R2.2* while avoiding a leak.

### Conclusion

Due to the special lifetime management (using expiration dates) for a `CollectionView` of a collection that does not implement `INotifyCollectionChanged`, the `CollectionView` is kept alive (in memory) much longer. And because the `CollectionView` in general has a strong reference to its source collection, this collection and its items and all reachable references are also kept alive much longer.

If the collection had implemented `INotifyCollectionChanged`, then the view manager would not have stored the strong reference to the `CollectionView` and therefore the `CollectionView` would have been garbage collected the moment it is no longer referenced and the source collection became unreachable.

The important point is, the lifetime of the strong reference to the `CollectionView` is managed by the `ViewManager` i.e. binding engine. Due to the management algorithm (the expiration date and the occasional purge), this lifetime is significantly extended.
Therefore, the observation of the persisting allocated memory after all references to the collection and its views have been destroyed is deceiving. It is not a real memory leak.

### Tips

> *"Is there any way to force release view or CollectionView from cache?"*

The lifetime management of the `CollectionView` instances are low-level framework internals that are not controllable from client code.
However, we can control the parameters of this internal algorithm to allow for a significantly shorter lifetime of the `CollectionView` and its reference graph:

1. Reuse the collection: reusing the collection means reusing the associated `CollectionView`. This is a lot cheaper than replacing a collection (and therefore replacing its view).
2. For data binding to a collection or a `CollectionView` or when we explicitly create a `CollectionView` by calling `CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView` we must prefer to use a collection that implements `INotifyCollectionChanged` when possible: as explained in this post, a collection that implements `INotifyCollectionChanged` allows the binding engine to store the reference to the `CollectionView` by using a `WeakReference`. Collections that implement `INotifyCollectionChanged` are subject to the common garbage collection rules and are not kept alive by the binding engine (`ViewManager`).
   Remember, the `ViewManager` has to guarantee that the
   `CollectionView` is alive as long as its source collection is alive.
   The `INotifyCollectionChanged.CollectionChanged` event allows this,
   as subscribing to an event always implicitly creates a strong
   reference to the listener (the `ColectionView`). If the collection
   doesn't implement `INotifyCollectionChanged`, this strong reference
   has to be created explicitly by the `ViewManager` (this is what we
   want to avoid when possible).
3. If we can't use a collection that implements `INotifyCollectionChanged` and the collection is very big (in terms of memory) or contains expensive references (in terms of allocated resources), we can at least ensure that:

   - there are no external references to the collection or `CollectionView` (as this would further extend the lifetime).
     For example, if your custom collection observes the `INotifyPropertyChanged.PropertyChanged` event of its items, always ensure that the event handlers are removed when the items are removed from the collection. Using a `WeakEvenManager` implementation like the `PropertyChangedEventManager` or the generic `WeakEvenManager<TSource,TArgs>` can improve the lifetime management or fix a related bug.
   - we have cleared the collection e.g. in a `IDisposable.Dispose` method.
     Clearing the collection at least ensures that the reference graph is freed i.e. eligible for garbage collection, so that only the empty `CollectionView` resides in memory until the final purge.
     While implementing `IDisposable` provides a good degree of reliability when the lifetime of the declaring instance is managed by some other objects, we have to make sure we always clear the collection in case we internally replace the instance too:

     ```
       // Calling Clear() leaves an empty CollectionView 
       // in memory (pending for GC collection).
       this.MyList.Clear();

       // Creating a new instance and binding to it
       // forces the binding engine to create 
       // a new CollectionView for this instance too.
       // However, because we previously cleared the collection,
       // the old items can get garbage collected long time before
       // the old (and now empty) List<T> instance.
       this.MyList = new List<object>();

       // Alternatively, reuse the previously
       // cleared collection (recommended)
       this.MyList.AddRange(newItems);
     ```
4. And for the sake of completeness: the variable that holds the collection or `CollectionView` instance must not be a class variable (`static` variable).

Comment: Is there any way to force release view or CollectionView from cache? In my case ViewModel is heavy object with some closures on disposable object. When I close view, I dispose that objects, but they still persists in memory for a long time because of cachin of them.

Comment: I have added the answer to your question to the bottom of this post. If you are concerned with the item objects and not the CollectionView then you can pressure the GC to free the allocated memory. But this is not recommended as it likely will negatively impact the overall performance of your application. The GC is already highly optimized to maximize its efficiency. If your concern is about the CollectionView then please read the last part of my answer that I have just added. Let me know if this doesn't answer your question or something is unclear.

Answer (score 0):

I had a look at your example with JustTrace memory profiler and apart from an obvious question why would you kill view model / nullify DataContext and leave view running (in 99.9% of cases you'd kill View and DataContext - hence ViewModel and Bindings go of of scope automatically) here's what I found.

It will work fine if you modify your example to:

- replace DataContext with new instance of view model, as expected, existing instances of Person go out of scope as MS.Internal.Data.DataBingingEngine flushes all bindings, even they were strong refs not managed by WeakPropertyChangedEventManager , or:
- ViewModel  to replace List with new instance of IEnumerable i.e. new Person[0]/simply null and raise INCP.PropertyChanged("List") on the ViewModel

Above modifications prove you can safely use IEnumerable/IEnumerable in binding. BTW, Person class doesn't need to implement INPC neither - TypeDescriptor binding/Mode=OneTime don't make any difference in this case, I verified that too. BTW, bindings to IEnumerable/IEnumerable/IList are wrapped into EnumerableCollectionView internal class. Unfortunatelly, I didn;t have a chance to go through MS.Internal/System.ComponentModel code to find out why ObservableCollection works when setting DataContext = null, probably because Microsoft guys did a special handing when unsubscribing from CollectionChanged. Feel free to waste few precious lifetime hours on going through MS.Internal/ComponentModel :) Hope It helps