# WPF Combobox selection disappears when the an item is deleted in the list bound to combobox

Tags: c#, wpf, combobox

I have a combo box rigged as

`<ComboBox x:Name="HeadComboBox"
  ItemsSource="{Binding DataContext.HeadList, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor,AncestorType= {x:Type views:FixedAssetBaseWholeUC}}}"   Margin="195,78,86,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"  SelectedItem="{Binding HeadItem}" DisplayMemberPath="Name" />`

The datacontext.HeadList will point to:

```
public List<FixedAssetHeadItem> HeadList
    {
        get
        {
            return _headList;
        }
        set
        {
            if (_headList != value)
            {
                _headList = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged("HeadList");
            }
        }
    }
```

I disable the UserControl in which the combobox rests and load another control to edit the items in the headlist by

```
            DeleteFromHeadList(1);

            FixedAssetBaseWholeViewModel fbwvm = (FixedAssetBaseWholeViewModel)Fabwuc.DataContext;
            fbwvm.HeadList = HeadList;
```

When the edit is complete the re enable the usercontrol only to find the selection disappers.

Debug shows
http://postimg.org/image/hdz4h4px3/

How should I deal with this?

Comment: Whenever your selected item becomes null or selected index is -1 then you can check in the setter property and then set it back to first item or first index.
You can create a property binding to selected index and set that too.

Comment: Where will I find the setter property off selected item?

Comment: I use the `DeleteFromHeadList` to check and never delete an item that is already linked to another object.  So in no way the selection becomes a null on my part.

Comment: If this is how a property is defined then
`public dynamic HeadItem
 {
  get { return headItem;}
     **set
     {
         headItem = value;
         // This is setter in your view model
     }**
 }`
In bold is your setter

Answer (score 0):

You should not bind to List ([can cause memory leak](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19511341/binding-to-list-causes-memory-leak)), but bind to `ObservableCollection<>` instead. In this way, your ComboBox should update appropriately. Also your `HeadItem` should be INPC property - in setter (private or public, depends on your code) should be raising of property changes.