# IEnumerable<T> or ObservableCollection<T> for getter in WPF project?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I have collection with some items.

```
public List<T> Collection { get; set; }
```

And i need to show part of this collection in `DataGrid` or `ListView`.

```
public IEnumerable<T> PartOfCollection => Collection.Where(item => item.SomeField == SomeValue);
public int SomeValue { get; set; }

<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding PartOfCollection}"/>
```

PartOfCollection may be changed.
I know that binding to non-implementing `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface collection can create memory leaks.

Do I need to cast PartOfCollection to `ObservableCollection` like this:

```
public ObservableCollection<T> PartOfCollection=> new ObservableCollection(Collection.Where(item => item.SomeField == SomeValue);
```

or use `IEnumerable`?

Comment: Using ObservableCollection is pointless as long as you only create a new collection from a subset of Collection. Its purpose is to notify about collection changes, i.e. when you add, remove or move elements, which you don't do here.

Comment: Binding to `ObservableCollection` is preferable in WPF, as the WPF binder has special implementation for `INotifyCollectionChanged` (or `ObservableCollection`). If you will bind to ordinary `List<T>`, it may lead to memory leak. See here for details https://stackoverflow.com/a/19511796/2011071

Comment: If you use a constant collection until you close a program, List does the trick. However, if you want to change the collection in any way (add, remove, or update an item), you should use ObservableCollection, and also if you delete the control your collection is attached to (since you want to remove the binding as well).

Comment: you can use CollectionView.Filter instead : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/data/how-to-filter-data-in-a-view

Comment: @Serg This is not a memory leak. See [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70027009/3141792) to understand the details. If this was a leak you wouldn't be able to bind to types like DataTable etc. Then this would have been well documented by Microsoft. This would also imply that the whole WPF binding system is useless.