# Memory leak in WPF application using ListView with ObservableCollection

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, listview, memory-leaks

I have a WPF application using this ListView:

```xml
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Log.Entries}"
          VirtualizingPanel.IsVirtualizing="True"
          VirtualizingPanel.IsVirtualizingWhenGrouping="True">
    <i:Interaction.Behaviors>
        <afutility:AutoScrollBehavior/>
    </i:Interaction.Behaviors>
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <WrapPanel>
                <TextBlock Foreground="{Binding Path=LogLevel, Mode=OneTime, Converter={StaticResource LogLevelToBrushConverter}}"
                           Text="{Binding Path=RenderedContent, Mode=OneTime}"/>
            </WrapPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

Log.Entries ends up at an instance of this class (the List itself is never replaced, it is always the same object):

```cs
public class RingList<T> : IList<T>, INotifyCollectionChanged, INotifyPropertyChanged
```

That class is essentially a custom list, which caps its content at 100 items. Adding an item at capacity removes an item from the head. For each added/removed item I call `CollectionChanged` like this:

```cs
// For added items
CollectionChanged?.Invoke(this, new NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs(NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Add, item, Count - 1));

// For removed items (only ever removes from the start of the ring)
CollectionChanged?.Invoke(this, new NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs(NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Remove, headItem, 0));
```

The items of the collection are NOT an object, they are a struct like this:

```cs
public struct RecordedLogEntry : IEquatable<RecordedLogEntry> {
    public string RenderedContent { get; set; }
    public Level LogLevel { get; set; }

    // [...] Equals, GetHashCode, ToString, etc omitted for brevity, all standard
}
```

I am aware of the fact, that binding to non INotifyPropertyChange objects can cause memory leaks (see: [Can bindings create memory leaks in WPF?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18542940/can-bindings-create-memory-leaks-in-wpf) )

That is why I used the `Mode=OneTime` to (hopefully) avoid that.
However, profiling speaks a different language.

This is a memory dump taken at runtime after a few hours of work, which usually leads to system being out of memory if not handled:

[image: Memory Profile - 728487 instances referenced by ListView]

You can clearly see:

- The 100 items in the capped collection
- A little above that, 12 items referenced by the currently visible ListViewItem instances (since the list view is virtualizing items, this is about the expected amount)
- over 700k instances referenced by the ListView itself
- The resulting massive amount of data which accumulated over time

The project is using .NET 4.7.2 on Windows.

How can I avoid this leak?

Edit, disregard this requirement:

> Ideally, I don't want to change away from a struct, as I have many of these items produced in the background (which don't all make it to the displayed 100 items) so I want to keep the footprint of the log entries small.

As @Joe rightfully pointed out, that is premature optimization. The fact remains that those log entries are not purely for UI display and are used elsewhere.
None of them change content at lifetime, so having an implementation to notify about changes seems counterintuitive.
Is there a way to make the binding not care about updates and do a real **one time** binding in this use case, or is the only option to add a wrapper class/copy the data into a class which implements `INotifyPropertyChange` just so the memory leak goes away?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Binding to list causes memory leak](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19511341/binding-to-list-causes-memory-leak)

Comment: Changing your `RecordedLogEntry` from a struct to a class is unlikely to increase your footprint by very much, if anything.  Sounds like a premature optimization.  Each LogEntry already contains a string and an enum, the size savings is likely to be dwarfed by the size of each entry's string itself.    I were trying to fix a problem like this, I would remove any optimizations (like trying struct instead of a class), fix the leak, and only *then* think about going back to struct

Comment: "Does this answer your question? Binding to list causes memory leak"

Partially. I am aware that implementing INotifyPropertyChange on the items (log entry here) will likely solve it - I'd like to not do that, as that struct is used elsewhere.

Comment: "Changing your RecordedLogEntry from a struct to a class [...] Each LogEntry already contains a string" You are correct that is not likely a huge impact. Just changing to a class will likely not fix that issue anyways, more likely implementing INotifyPropertyChanged would fix it (see above). I'll edit and include that reasoning in the question. Thank you for your input!

Comment: I think you should create a small blank project and then try to reproduce your observed issue in order to create a minimal viable example. Then post this code so that we can review it. Chances are high that you can fix the issue yourself while reproducing it that way.

Comment: The screenshot and snippets are not helpful in order to identify a potential leak. From what you wrote so far, it does not look like the leak is related to data binding. If there is a leak. Maybe you constantly create new copies of your struct on the heap by accidental boxing. Structs are usually memory allocated on the stack. Also note that structs are recommended to be immutable (yours is mutable).

Comment: You should also consider to raise a single CollectionChanged event instead of two consecutive. You could set the action to `NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Replace` and set the `NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs.OldStartingIndex` property to the removed index and the `NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs.NewStartingIndex` to the insertion index. Then set `NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs.NewItems` and `NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs.OldItems` accordingly. This can further improve performance.

Comment: Thank you all for your input. I will take it into account for further improvement, both code and question quality. Unfortunately the issue was not reproducible with a minimal example, so I have to assume the instances are kept alive elsewhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately the issue was not reproducible with a minimal example, so I have to assume the instances are kept alive elsewhere.

A minimal example which would normally show the leak easily, if it came from the bindings:

```xml
<Window x:Class="ListViewLeakRepro.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
    <Grid>
        <ListView Margin="10,46,10,10"
                  ItemsSource="{Binding Entries}"
                  VirtualizingPanel.IsVirtualizing="True"
                  VirtualizingPanel.IsVirtualizingWhenGrouping="True"
                  VirtualizingPanel.ScrollUnit="Pixel">
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <WrapPanel>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=RenderedContent, Mode=OneTime}"/>
                    </WrapPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
        <Button Content="Start Indirect Log Spam" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,10,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Click="StartTimerIndirect"/>
        <Button Content="Start Direct Log Spam" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="143,10,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Click="StartTimerDirect"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Code behind:

```cs
using System.Windows;

namespace ListViewLeakRepro {
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window {
        MainWindowModel Model { get; }

        public MainWindow() {
            InitializeComponent();

            Model = new MainWindowModel();
            DataContext = Model;
        }

        private void StartTimerIndirect(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {
            Model.StartTimerIndirect();
        }

        private void StartTimerDirect(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {
            Model.StartTimerDirect();
        }
    }
}
```

Model:

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Threading;

namespace ListViewLeakRepro {
    public class MainWindowModel : INotifyPropertyChanged {
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        public RingList<RecordedLogEntry> Entries { get; } = new RingList<RecordedLogEntry>(100);

        private static List<RecordedLogEntry> pollCache = new List<RecordedLogEntry>();
        private static List<RecordedLogEntry> pollCache2 = new List<RecordedLogEntry>();

        private DispatcherTimer timer;
        private DispatcherTimer timer2;
        private int logCounter = 0;

        private static readonly object lockObject = new object();

        public void StartTimerIndirect() {
            if (timer != null) {
                return;
            }
            timer = new DispatcherTimer(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(10), DispatcherPriority.Background, SpamLogIndirect, Application.Current.Dispatcher);
            timer2 = new DispatcherTimer(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(500), DispatcherPriority.Background, RefreshLogDisplay, Application.Current.Dispatcher);
        }

        public void StartTimerDirect() {
            if (timer != null) {
                return;
            }
            timer = new DispatcherTimer(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(10), DispatcherPriority.Background, SpamLogDirect, Application.Current.Dispatcher);
        }

        private void SpamLogIndirect(object sender, EventArgs e) {
            // Add some invisible junk data to have results earlier
            byte[] junkData = new byte[50 * 1024 * 1024];

            lock (lockObject) {
                pollCache.Add(new RecordedLogEntry($"Entry {++logCounter}", junkData));
            }
        }

        private void SpamLogDirect(object sender, EventArgs e) {
            // Add some invisible junk data to have results earlier
            byte[] junkData = new byte[50 * 1024 * 1024];

            lock (lockObject) {
                Entries.Add(new RecordedLogEntry($"Entry {++logCounter}", junkData));
            }
        }

        private void RefreshLogDisplay(object sender, EventArgs e) {
            lock (lockObject) {
                // Swap background buffer
                (pollCache, pollCache2) = (pollCache2, pollCache);
            }

            foreach (RecordedLogEntry item in pollCache2) {
                Entries.Add(item);
            }

            pollCache2.Clear();
        }
    }
}
```

The RingList class:

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections.Specialized;
using System.ComponentModel;

namespace ListViewLeakRepro {
    /// <summary>
    /// A collection with a fixed buffer size which is reused when full.
    /// Only the most recent items are retained, the oldest are overwritten,
    /// always keeping a constant amount of items in the collection without reallocating memory.
    /// </summary>
    /// <typeparam name="T"></typeparam>
    public class RingList<T> : IList<T>, INotifyCollectionChanged, INotifyPropertyChanged {
        private T[] buffer;
        private int head;
        private int tail;
        private bool firstRevolution;

        public event NotifyCollectionChangedEventHandler CollectionChanged;
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        public RingList(int capacity) {
            buffer = new T[capacity];
            firstRevolution = true;
        }

        public int Capacity {
            get {
                return buffer.Length;
            }

            set {
                T[] oldBuffer = buffer;
                int oldHead = head;
                // int oldTail = tail;

                int oldLength = Count;

                buffer = new T[value];
                head = 0;
                tail = 0;

                for (int i = 0; i < oldLength; i++) {
                    Add(oldBuffer[(oldHead + i) % oldBuffer.Length]);
                }
                PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(nameof(Capacity)));
                CollectionChanged?.Invoke(this, new NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs(NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Reset));
            }
        }

        public int IndexOf(T item) {
            for (int i = 0; i < Count; i++) {
                if (Equals(this[i], item)) {
                    return i;
                }
            }
            return -1;
        }

        public void Insert(int index, T item) => throw new NotImplementedException();

        public void RemoveAt(int index) => throw new NotImplementedException();

        public bool Remove(T item) => throw new NotImplementedException();

        public T this[int index] {
            get {
                if (index < 0 || index >= Count) {
                    throw new IndexOutOfRangeException();
                }
                int actualIndex = (index + head) % Capacity;
                return buffer[actualIndex];
            }
            set {
                if (index < 0 || index > Count) {
                    throw new IndexOutOfRangeException();
                }
                int actualIndex = (index + head) % Capacity;
                T previous = buffer[actualIndex];
                buffer[actualIndex] = value;
                CollectionChanged?.Invoke(this, new NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs(NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Replace, value, previous, index));
            }
        }

        public void Add(T item) {
            if (Count == Capacity) {
                RemoveHead();
            }

            buffer[tail] = item;
            tail++;
            if (tail == Capacity) {
                tail = 0;
                head = 0;
                firstRevolution = false;
            }

            CollectionChanged?.Invoke(this, new NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs(NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Add, item, Count - 1));
        }

        private void RemoveHead() {
            if (Count == 0) {
                throw new InvalidOperationException("Cannot remove from an empty collection");
            }
            T headItem = buffer[head];
            head++;
            if (head == Capacity) {
                head = 0;
            }
            CollectionChanged?.Invoke(this, new NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs(NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Remove, headItem, 0));
        }

        public void Clear() {
            buffer = new T[buffer.Length];
            head = 0;
            tail = 0;
            firstRevolution = true;
            CollectionChanged?.Invoke(this, new NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs(NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Reset));
        }

        public bool Contains(T item) => IndexOf(item) >= 0;

        public void CopyTo(T[] array, int arrayIndex) => throw new NotImplementedException();

        public void CopyTo(List<T> collection) {
            if (collection == null) {
                throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(collection));
            }

            for (int i = 0; i < Count; i++) {
                collection.Add(this[i]);
            }
        }

        public int Count {
            get {
                if (tail == head) {
                    if (firstRevolution) {
                        return 0;
                    } else {
                        return Capacity;
                    }
                } else if (tail < head) {
                    return Capacity - head + tail;
                } else {
                    return tail - head;
                }
            }
        }

        public bool IsReadOnly => false;

        public IEnumerator<T> GetEnumerator() {
            int position = 0; // state
            while (position < Count) {
                yield return this[position];
                position++;
            }
        }

        IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator() => GetEnumerator();
    }
}
```

The items of the collection:

```cs
namespace ListViewLeakRepro {
    public class RecordedLogEntry {
        public RecordedLogEntry(string renderedContent, byte[] junkData) {
            RenderedContent = renderedContent;
            JunkData = junkData;
        }

        public string RenderedContent { get; set; }
        public byte[] JunkData { get; set; }
    }
}
```

---

**Analysis with above reproduction code**

Starting the simulation using "Direct" log spam, i.e. directly writing to `Entries` does NOT cause a leak.

It consumes lots of memory, but GC is able to clear it:
[image: spikes with linear increase]

Starting the simulation using "Indirect" log spam, i.e. collecting entries in a buffer which is rotated every 500ms, seemingly causes a memory leak. GC is not clearing it right away:

[image: linear consumption, with hump at the start]

But eventually it does, it just takes longer:

[image: longer spikes with slower linear consumption]

Conclusion: Not a leak in the binding, more likely an unbounded growth in one of the buffers or some other place keeping the instance alive.

Side note: changing from class to struct does not significantly impact the situation (may change overall consumption, but does not cause or solve the issue).

Comment: If you inspect the memory using a profiler you usually can also check the object graph. It will show you the GC roots and reference trees in general. When you find your instances in the tree, you can easily see all references to this instance. This will help you to understand which instances affect their lifetime. You can use the Visual Studio profiler. Just take a snapshot and start the inspection. You can also download a trial of JetBrain's dotMemory, which is a very powerful memory profiler, easy to use. Inspecting the references also allows you to jump to the related code lines.

Comment: If you have checked the obvious critical code without success, you must always use a profiler. This is your only chance. Like you would use the debugger to identify a bug.

Comment: *"seemingly causes a memory leak. GC is not clearing it right away"* - This is not a leak as allocated memory is released. A leak exists when the GC is *never* able to collect references. Also be cautious with your static members. The instances they reference (and the references of this references - the complete reference tree starting from the static instance root) will never be eligible for collection. Events are another notorious source for leaks: always unsubscribe.Dispose IDisposable and implement IDisposable where necessary.

Comment: You can see in my screenshots above that I actually am using a profiler on a memory dump. The only active references to my data structs come from `ListView->EffectiveValueEntry[]->MS.Internal.WeakDictionary->WeakObjectHashtable->Hastable+bucket[]`. This never occurs when running in debugger, with the memory snapshots there.

Comment: "This is not a leak as allocated memory is released." Hence the "seemingly". Just the fact that it takes so long to get cleared, consuming 20+ GB of memory before they are released, certainly looks like a leak. Until it doesn't anymore.

Comment: "Also be cautious with your static members." Which is why I am now trimming down their capacity when rotating. Did not have an impact on the memory consumption. BUT: The whole system did not crash anymore since then. So it **could** be, that the runtime is now properly freeing memory and giving it back to the system as needed, which may not have happened before due to those two statics growing and never shrinking capacity. I just know of no way of proving that.