# Wpf MVVM Datagrid is empty but it shouldn't be

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I am having trouble with making binding works in simple WPF GridView scenario. When some event happens list is updated (new element added) but my grid always show 0 elements. Since it is ObservableCollection I assumed it should work automatically but it doesn't.

This is my ViewModel:

```
public class ReportSyncerStatusViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    public ObservableCollection<ReportEntity> SuccessReports { get; private set; }

    public ObservableCollection<ReportEntity> FailedReports { get; private set; }        

    public ReportSyncerStatusViewModel()
    {
        SuccessReports = new ObservableCollection<ReportEntity>();
        FailedReports = new ObservableCollection<ReportEntity>();
        Messenger.Default.Register<ReportSyncCompletedMessage>(this, OnReportSyncCompletedMessage);    
    }

    private void OnReportSyncCompletedMessage(ReportSyncCompletedMessage obj)
    {
        SuccessReports = new ObservableCollection<ReportEntity>(obj.ReportSyncStatusUpload.SuccessReports);
        var a = this;
        FailedReports = new ObservableCollection<ReportEntity>(obj.ReportSyncStatusUpload.FailedReports);
    }
}
```

This is XAML:

```
<Window xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
     xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
     xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
     xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup- compatibility/2006"
     xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MyApp"
     xmlns:dxg="http://schemas.devexpress.com/winfx/2008/xaml/grid" x:Class="MyApp.ReportSyncStatusView"
     mc:Ignorable="d"
     DataContext="{Binding ReportSyncStatusViewModel, Source={StaticResource locator}}"
     Loaded="Window_Loaded"
     Title="ReportSyncStatusView" Height="450" Width="800">
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="40"/>
        <RowDefinition/>
        <RowDefinition Height="40"/>
        <RowDefinition/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <TextBlock Grid.Row="0"
               Text="Successfully uploaded reports">

    </TextBlock>
    <DataGrid Grid.Row="1" 
              AutoGenerateColumns="False"
              IsReadOnly="True"
              ItemsSource="{Binding Path=SuccessReports}">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="VinNumber" Width="200" Binding="{Binding VinNumber}"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="StartTime" Width="200" Binding="{Binding StartTime}"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="EndTime" Width="200" Binding="{Binding EndTime}"/>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
    <TextBlock  Grid.Row="2" 
                Text="Failed uploaded reports">

    </TextBlock>
    <DataGrid  Grid.Row="3"
               IsReadOnly="True"  
               AutoGenerateColumns="False"
               ItemsSource="{Binding Path=FailedReports}">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="VinNumber" Width="200" Binding="{Binding VinNumber}"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="StartTime" Width="200" Binding="{Binding StartTime}"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="EndTime" Width="200" Binding="{Binding EndTime}"/>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
</Grid>
```

I have FailedReports and SuccessReport populated (at least then OnReportSyncCompletedMessage is called, and actually it is called, but my grid always remain at 0 elements)

EDIT: When I initialize inside constructor one element, that one element is shown so problem is inside OnReportSyncCompletedMessage method, the way I am settings FailedReports property is somehow wrong

Comment: could you show your classes FailedReports and SuccessReport ?

Comment: just POCO with public getters and setters. I will add them to question anyway

Comment: In your OnReportSyncCompletedMessage try clearing the ObservableCollection and repopulate instead of assigning a new reference. This may be slower and not a viable solution for your use case, but could point to the UI element not being notified of changes.

Comment: That works, adding element one by one instead of creating new isntance

Comment: You really should not just add one item at a time; instead you should trigger `PropertyChanged` on the setter of `SuccessReports`.

Answer (score 0):

Careful. Some performance assumptions that were made and the resulting recommendations are wrong: replacing the collection instance usually results in a much worse performance penalty opposed to manipulating the collection (by a magnitude). This penalty becomes more relevant the bigger the collection is.

There are a lot of things going on under the hoods. WPF's binding engine is doing a lot more than just delegating data from one property to another. If the data source is a collection, the binding engine will hook onto the `INotifyCollectionChanged.CollectionChanged` event, creates a `CollectionView` (or looks up an existing `CollectionView`) and does some collection view management to improve efficiency.

The binding engine tracks the lifetime of each `CollectionView` to avoid persistent strong references that would result in memory leaks (especially when binding to collections that don't implement `INotifyCollectionChanged`).

Because the lifetime management algorithm polls for `CollectionView` instances that qualify to be released (their strong reference is removed from the view table) in a specific amount of time (expiration time - usually a timer triggered/reset by GC operations), you will end up with collections being kept alive long long time after they were discarded by the framework's client code (for example when the client code replaces the collection instance). Then add to the this expiration time the time it takes for the GC to finally free the eligible allocations (the different generations of all participating references). This lifetime management is often wrongfully identified as memory leak by many (because the collections appear to live in the memory permanently).

It's important to understand that in case a collection implements `INotifyCollectionChanged` the binding engine can subscribe to the event and create a weak reference to the actual `CollectionView` of this collection. But if the collection does not implement `INotifyCollectionChanged`, the engine is forced to keep a strong reference to the view. This strong reference is then subject to the lifetime management algorithm described above. This means, in a binding scenario we should always consider to use a `INotifyCollectionChanged` as source collection to help the binding engine to be more efficient. See the following answer [Binding to list causes memory leak](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70027009/3141792) to get a better and more detailed explanation.

This means changing the collection instance will incur a time and a huge memory penalty.

Then in addition we have the layout impact. Every collection instance change will result in (multiple) complete layout passes where the *complete* `ItemsControl` is invalidated (not only the hosting panel or its children).

If the collection is big and/or the visual tree of the item container is very deep it can become really time consuming as every item container is visited and its complete element subtree is measured and arranged again. Even a shallow item container tree will be slow enough.

But when using an `ObservableCollection`, or a collection that implements `INotifyCollectionChanged` in general, and we *modify* it instead of replacing it, the `ItemsControl` can apply a much more efficient algorithm as it now is able to focus on the new/changed items alone.
Also when *modifying* the collection, the overhead of registering and managing the collection views is successfully eliminated (those costs only incur once). In addition, the `ItemsControl` is not completely invalidated. The only invalid layout is related to the items panel. For this reason, modifying a collection that serves as a binding source is always more efficient than replacing the collection instance.

When looking at the special case where UI virtualization is enabled, both modifying the instance vs replacing the instance yield approximately the same results in terms of efficiency. With virtualization enabled replacing the collection is expected to be *slightly* faster as the virtualizing panel doesn't have to re-validate the viewport. But when considering the extra memory costs (expensive) when replacing the instance, modifying the instance will always outperform replacing the instance.

### Solution

Following those performance considerations, the recommended approach is to consider to *modify* the source collection instead of replacing it:

```cs
private void OnReportSyncCompletedMessage(ReportSyncCompletedMessage obj)
{
  this.SuccessReports.Clear();
  foreach (var successfullReport in obj.ReportSyncStatusUpload.SuccessReports)
  {
    this.SuccessReports.Add(successfullReport);
  }

  this.FailedReports.Clear();
  foreach (var failedReport in obj.ReportSyncStatusUpload.FailedReports)
  {
    this.FailedReports.Add(successfullReport);
  }
}
```

Alternatively, if you insist on replacing the instance, you must remember to notify the binding target about the property change and raise the `INotifyPropertyCVhanged.PropertyChanged` event:

```cs
private ObservableCollection<ReportEntity> successReports;
public ObservableCollection<ReportEntity> SuccessReports 
{ 
  get => this.successReports; 
  private set
  {
    this.successReports = value;
    OnPropertyChanged();
  } 
}

private ObservableCollection<ReportEntity> failedReports;
public ObservableCollection<ReportEntity> FailedReports
{ 
  get => this.failedReports; 
  private set
  {
    this.failedReports = value;
    OnPropertyChanged();
  } 
}
```