# Memory footprint buildup after repeated window opening in WPF

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

My organization is building a new app in WPF. During development, we've noticed that opening and closing one of the windows repeatedly leads to an increase in memory that doesn't seem to clear down. Opening/closing the window more leads to higher RAM usage.

I've managed to narrow the behaviour down to a possible root cause: binding collection views in XAML to ObservableCollections in DataContext, where the DataContext is contained entirely in the lifetime of the window. For instance:

MainWindow:

```
using System.Windows;

namespace TestMemLeak
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            new TestWindow().ShowDialog();
        }
    }
}
```

with XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="TestMemLeak.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:TestMemLeak"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
    <Grid>
        <Button Click="Button_Click"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

TestWindow XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="TestMemLeak.TestWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:TestMemLeak"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="TestWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
    <d:Window.DataContext>
        <local:TestDataContext/>
    </d:Window.DataContext>
    <Grid>
        <TreeView ItemsSource="{Binding Data}"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

with code behind:

```
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.Windows;

namespace TestMemLeak
{
    public class TestDataContext : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public ObservableCollection<string> Data { get; private set; } = new ObservableCollection<string>();

        public TestDataContext()
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
                Data.Add(i.ToString());
        }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    }

    public partial class TestWindow : Window
    {
        public TestWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            DataContext = new TestDataContext();
        }
    }
}
```

This is a very simplified representation of our scenario: click a button that opens a window with a TreeView that binds to a ObservableCollection of items.
After opening and closing a few times, and using the memory snapshot feature, I can see memory usage has slightly increased after each cycle. The snapshot details confirms this:

[image: List of objects in memory showing net increase in objects and memory usage]

For instance here, I can see the instance count for TestWindow has increased by 2, despite there only being 1 window open at a time. Inspecting one of the instances, I can see:

[image: Instances of TestWindow in memory]

If I understand this correctly, it means the instances of my TestWindow are being kept around by the references from the EventHandlers

After browsing reference source, I believe this happens because the ItemsControl (TreeView) uses WeakEventManager to create Weak Events to attach to INotifyCollectionChanged events (normal). However, the WeakEventManager will only free up the EventHandler when it notices that the object is due collection (WeakRef pattern) after the event is triggered, but since the original publisher no longer fires events after the window is closed, WeakEventManager never looks to clear down old references and thus the control and by extension the window remain in RAM.

I may be misunderstanding this, and please correct me if I am. Is there any way to resolve this? I'm sure that WPF mmust have ways to mitigate or avoid this effect.

P.S. This is using .NET 4.8

Comment: Make sure that everything you are binding to implements one of the `INotify*` interfaces. I have had problems with leaks when binding to regular objects/collections.

Comment: Your viewmodel does not implement inotifypropertychanged. This results in hard references. Add the interface to any and all viewmodels. I recommend doing so by using the base classes for viewmodels in the mvvm community toolkit.

Comment: The Window is not kept alive. Closing the Window will free all related memory. Unless the DataContext value is referenced outside the Window instance, the complete reference tree will become eligible for garbage collection. The DataContext object reference can't live without the Window. Collection views are managed by the binding engine. If the binding source collection implements INotifyCollectionChanged the binding engine will maintain a weak reference to the collection view.

Comment: If the collection doesn't implement this interface the binding engine will maintain a strong reference. Those strong references are purged periodically by the binding engine. It could take a while until the allocated memory is freed. You can read [this explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70027009/3141792) to understand more how collection views are managed. Weak references on the other hand use `GCHandle.Alloc` to allow the GC to track the object.

Comment: *"WeakEventManager will only free up the EventHandler when it notices that the object is due collection"* - WeakEventManager manages only weak references. It stores a WeakReference to the listener (the event source has a strong reference to the WeakEventManager). This means, the listener is *always* eligible for garbage collection and garbage collection could occur any time unless there exists a strong reference to the managed listener.

Comment: When the listener gets finally collected, the WeakEventManager will remove the dead WeakReference object reference from the table. But it's important that at this point the listener was already garbage collected i.e. allocated memory is already freed. The whole point of the WeakEventManager is to break the dependency of the lifetime from the listener to the publisher by removing the strong reference from publisher to listener (introduced by the delegate).

Comment: You generally need to have patience with the GC. Wait a few minutes. The memory allocation of your application should then go down. Especially the collection views are kept alive for a while. Please let me know if this isn't the case, but wait for about 5 minutes.

Comment: If yyour binding source doesn't implement INotifyPropertyChanged the binding engine will use the PropertyDescriptor to observe the source object for property changes. The engine will store a strong reference to the PropertyDexcriptor in a static table. The data source therefore becomes a GC root object (marked as "not collectible" by the GC).

Comment: Aside from that, the binding engine will have to make heavy use of reflection in order to obtain the PropertyDescriptor. This is because it first has to get the TypeDescriptor. For performance reasons and to avoid memory leaks you must always let your data source implement INotifyPropertyChanged of extend DependencyObject and expose the source properties as dependency properties.

Comment: Dependency properties require no reflection at all while INotifyPropertyChanged requires some reflection (the engine only sees a INotifyPropertyChanged object but has to resolve the property path of the binding to get/set the property value) but far less than the PropertyDescriptor method.

Comment: Hi guys, I've added INotifyPropertyChanged interface to the DataContext class but this has made no difference to the memory footprint increase. I'm testing if there's any time dependence (waiting 5 mins), but would like to know if there's any way to speed up GC in this respect, since in our application it can lead to a fair bit of memory increase over a short time span.

Comment: Force garbage collection and see what happens.

Comment: @Andy no more luck I'm afraid. This doesn't seem to help much, although I have noticed that after numerous cycles (maybe 15-20 window open/closes), memory usage seems to stabilise, although still at a higher value than the first window open

Comment: Garbage collection is very resource intensive. To reduce the performance impact as much as possible, the garbage collection follows a strict algorithm. You shouldn't interfere with the GC explicitly especially in production code. The GC will always manage the memory properly. For example WPF is able to reuse collection views for reasons of performance (because registering and tracking them comes with an overhead). For example forcing those views to be collected prematurely would eliminate all performance optimizations of the WPF framework. Instead optimize your client code.

Comment: You can use the following code to force GC. But still, it is not guaranteed that the GC collects everything. It's a very complex algorithm. `for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
{
GC.Collect(2, GCCollectionMode.Forced, true);
GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
}`.

Comment: You should review your code using a profiler. Identify the objects that remain in memory and check your options to shorten their lifetime.

Comment: For example use WeakEventManager or WeakReference<T> where necessary. Eliminate static variables (GC roots). Avoid capturing instance variables in lambda expressions (use locals). Always unsubscribe from events when possible. If you have critical event handlers that don't allow to unsubscribe themselves consider to implement IDisposable and unsubscribe on instance disposal. Ensure to call Dispose() (or use using-expression) for *all* IDisposables to free unmanaged and managed resources. Take proper care of unmanaged code. In case your application uses caching, manage the cache properly.

Comment: As a note, your posted example does not qualify to create any memory leaks.

Comment: This may not relevant, but you are creating two TestDataContext instances for each TestWindow instance: one in XAML and one in code-behind. In case this is how your real code is implemented you must fix this as you create one complete instance just to throw it away. But it will still cost CPU (the for-loop and UI layout refresh) and memory (the binding meta data and the generated items and item containers). This is another key refactoring to improve performance (reduce the memory footprint).

Comment: @BionicCode the code I edited still creates extra instances in Ram (last 3 screenshots) which shows increases in objects such as event handlers, viewcollections etc. I don't subscribe to any events, the code is as you see it there, but it still accrues memory, although adding GC.Collect and your collect function do seem to free up a lot of the objects. As for the DataContext, as I understood the d: means it would only be instantiated in the designer, not during runtime, and if I use a breakpoint it only gets hit once when opening the window.

Comment: @BionicCode After more testing I've found in our production code some extraneous instance creation, which after fixing, memory now stays constant after calling your ```GC.Collect(2, ...);``` function. However, if I don't call it, the memory does still increase. It seems that there are a lot of "survivors" after non-forced GC gen 2 collections in WPF after closing the window, most of them bein WeakReferences, EffectiveValueEntry[] etc. I'm guessing this is something internal to WPF, and I'm not sure there's a solution other than calling GC.Collect like you mentioned.

Comment: By definition, a memory leak is when the application allocates memory but is not able to free it. In managed languages like C# this only happens if you mishandle unmanaged resources (resources that are not managed by the garbage collector) or if you are writing flawed code that prevents the GC to collect managed resources (see my 12th comment to know some common pitfalls that prevent the GC from collecting references). As noted in comment #13 your code does not qualify for creating a memory leak. The fact that forcing the GC does improve or fixes the issue proves that there is no leak.

Comment: *"It seems that there are a lot of "survivors" after non-forced GC gen 2 collections in WPF after closing the window, most of them bein WeakReferences"* - The GC will take care sooner or later, for sure as that's its job. `WeakReference` is what it is: a weak reference. Unlike a strong reference a weak reference is *always* eligible for garbage collection unless the weak reference is referenced via a strong reference. This is the only case where a `WeakReference` can't be collected until the strong reference was destroyed.

Comment: So, you must review your code to check if you have any strong references to `WeakReference` instances e.g. by storing the instance wrapped into  the `WeakReference` in an instance variable like fields and properties. This means it is impossible that you experience a leak created by `WeakReference` objects unless you forcefully keep them alive. This is the *only* solution: fix your code. Do not force garbage collection in production code.

Comment: Sometimes an application consumes a lot of memory. A few hundred MB is not much nowadays. To improve the memory footprint review your application and try to refactor it to use caching (but manage the cache properly to avoid leaks). Caching allows to reduce the memory allocation by reusing existing instances and resources.

Comment: Avoid big strings like file contents (`string` is immutable and is copied in memory when passed around). Instead wrap such `string` objects into a `StingBuilder`. Don't use `struct` when the type holds expensive resources (is not lightweight). Do some refactoring to improve your code. Use a profiler like DotMemory to identify critical code.

Comment: Make sure to avoid some common code smells, mentioned in comment #12 of my posted comments.

Comment: *"For example use WeakEventManager or WeakReference<T> where necessary. Eliminate static variables (GC roots). Avoid capturing instance variables in lambda expressions (use locals). Always unsubscribe from events when possible. If you have critical event handlers that don't allow to unsubscribe themselves consider to implement IDisposable and unsubscribe on instance disposal. Ensure to call Dispose() (or use using-expression) for all IDisposables to free unmanaged and managed resources. Take proper care of unmanaged code. In case your application uses caching, manage the cache properly."*

Comment: @BionicCode I never said there was a memory leak, merely that the memory usage increases, which it does. You can see my code there: there's no references to WeakReference anywhere, and if I were keeping references, the GC.Collect would make no difference to the memory usage, since it wouldn't be able to free the references at all. All I can tell is that some WPF components make use of WeakReferences, which, containing finalizers, end up surviving collection in Gen 2, causing an increase of the Gen 2 heap space by .NET.

Comment: I have to apologize. Then I got you wrong. I somehow perceived your comments like you were thinking the GC is not able to free memory properly (which would be a memory leak). The only `WeakReference` objects that are created in relation to your posted code are those that hold the binding source (the INotifyPropertyChanged instance) and the ones to hold the reference to the collection view. But those are not responsible to allocate huge amount of memory. However, when I understood you correctly, you were trying to reproduce the issue you are experiencing with your real application.

Comment: My suggestions were all made with your real application in mind (because the current code example doesn't even allocate "any" memory at all. Those few bytes...). I just assumed that you have some different problems in your application that this example doesn't replicate (because you are not aware of that particular code that creates or adds to your problem, hence you didn't include it). That's why I posted general recommendations you should have in mind when reviewing your application code.

Comment: I recommend to get dotMemory from JetBrains (use grace period if you can't buy it) and then profile the application, first for a few minutes and then for several hours to see how the GC behaves. dotMemory allows you to investigate the memory with more details that will really help you to identify the problematic code. In addition with a careful code review of potentially resource intensive code will help you to further optimize your code. I'm pretty sure that this will help you to significantly improve the memory footprint of your application. I really hope you found my suggestion helpful.

Comment: I can somehow feel your disappointment. But your posted code really has no issues. It's perfect and clean code. That's why I was always referring to your real application. The issue is there. You are just not aware of it and that's why your posted example is not helping you. You have to put on your Sherlock monocle and review your code and profile your application. That's all you can do. And the suggestion I had made is all you can get. If you are part of a team, then this task could be assigned to a two man team to conduct the code review.

Comment: @BionicCode Yeah I was hoping it would be something in my code and not WPF. I'd say if you have access, try to run my program in Visual studio and use the snapshot feature to get the memory state, or run the Object Allocation profiler, or use WinDbg with SOS.dll loaded, and you'll also see a massive increase in object allocation after subsequent window open/close actions. I'd say your GC.Collect suggestion remedies this, which is why I was convinced it must be a WPF internal issue, such as WeakReference finalizers needing to complete. If you post it as an answer, I'll mark it as accepted.

Comment: What do yo mean by "massive"? We are talking about a few bytes... Allocated memory will be freed for sure (at least in context of your posted example). You are showing a very basic code. If this would create leaks or GC related memory issues in general then C# had a problem. GC is a language runtime matter and not at WPF (framework) level. When the heap is small, the pressure on the GC is low in favor of a better runtime performance. If the above code exactly replicates your original memory issue, then you don't have any problems. The observed GC behavior is normal.

Comment: @BionicCode if you can run the code you'll see what I'm getting at. Each window open/close leaves lots of allocated objects, which increases over time, totalling maybe 1MB per 20 cycles. This is obviously magnified for our production code, which has a larger scale.

Comment: A Window is a complex control. It's a classic WPF ContentControl. But it's also a low level Windows API interface or container. The Window is a OS level window that allocates a lot of unmanaged low level resources and tracks OS level input events: it is OS domain. The content of the Window, what is actually rendered in the OS low level container, is actual WPF framework domain.

Comment: This special nature makes a Window generally an expensive control. While all controls are usually pure framework controls, Window and CommonDialog (or dialogs in general) are not pure framework controls. This is why you should avoid to show Window instances at high frequencies. Window is expensive. The GC is very optimistic in terms of freeing allocated memory unless it gets pressurized e.g. by consuming certain amount of memory or by manually forcing a collect cycle.

Comment: I understand your problem. But again, if and only *if* your example replicates exactly the issue of your application, I can assure you that all is well. Review your code to check if you can improve performance and reconsider your decision to allow the user to randomly start new WIndow instances. Alternatively, toggle the Visibility (Hidden, Visible) of a single Window instance or prefer a single page application or use custom controls to show the dialog content.

Comment: Please start with installing dotMemor and profiling your application for a complete working day. Provoke the memory consumption to increase and then wait. Periodically take snapshots e.g. 1 per hour. At the end of your working day check the profiler. Either the memory is back to normal or you now have a good starting point based on your profiling.

Comment: Window even has a Hide() and (of course) Show() method.

Comment: That's a good point, I forgot about Window Show/Hide. If you put these points (GC Collect, Window show/hide) as an answer I'll mark it as accepted